# Session management : Refreshes a connection

Tags: sabre

I have implemented the SessionCreateRQ successfully and other service using **PHP** and I am confused what to do  when the security token has been expired. According to [documentation](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_basics/Performance) provided in the topic **Session management overview** , the session can be refreshed using the service **SessionValidateRQ** but I didn't find any documentation while I am searching. I only find the [Refresh Session](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/session_management/refresh_session) documentation while I am searching.

Does there is any documentation for the service **SessionValidateRQ** ?.
And I am little bit confused how to manage the session for the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you already checked the best practices related to performance and sessions.

Normally (and depending on your transactions volume) you would have a process/job that initiates a given amount of sessions at application startup, and refreshes them before they timeout. This is done to ensure users can complete the 'shopping' process on demand.

When it comes to booking, you can use the services PassengerDetails and EnhancedAirBook in sequence (after capturing passenger names, flights selected, etc) an'd use a 'short conversation (meaning you open the session using SessionCreateRQ, then call those two services in sequence, and then close the session using SessionCloseRQ)...

Comment: I am little bit confused can I use the same security token to issue more than one ticket or not ?

Comment: You can but not concurrently. No need to close the session, but need to make sure you clear the work area session with new PNR you are wanting to issue the ticket for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [OTA_PingRQ](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/session_management/refresh_session) in application I develop. In general every interaction with Sabre prolongates the session, however there are cases in which you would like to prolongate it manually.

Consider this case - timeout in Sabre happens after 15 minutes since last request to Sabre was sent, and you have got user that enters passenger data in your application. It's obvious sometimes user needs more than those 15 minutes to complete the action. In that case you may send OTA_PingRQ to Sabre after 14 minutes just to keep session alive (and now you have next 15 minute interval till expiration)

Comment: This is what I use.

Answer (score 0):

Currently i am using SessionValidateRQ for keep alive session.

```
msgHeader.Service = new Service();
            msgHeader.Service.Value = "SessionValidateRQ";
            msgHeader.Action = "SessionValidateRQ";

            //Set credentials to create session
            Security secure = new Security();
            secure.UsernameToken = new SecurityUsernameToken();
            secure.UsernameToken.Username = Config.WC_EPR;
            secure.UsernameToken.Password = Config.WC_PASSCODE;
            secure.UsernameToken.Organization = Config.WC_IPCC;
            secure.UsernameToken.Domain = Config.WC_DOMAIN;
            secure.BinarySecurityToken = sToken;
            Object ssValidateRq = new object();
            var ret = svc.SessionValidateRQ(ref msgHeader, ref secure, ssValidateRq);
```